# List of an enum in visual c++

Tags: list, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, enums

So I want to create multiple instances of the same enum and then store each enum in a list in Visual C++. I plan on using a generic list but would be open to any other ways to do it. Anyway when I create a `List` instance, I get the error that `Name is not a valid generic argument`. Thanks in advance for any help!

Basic code:

```
enum Name
{
    one, two, three,
};

void GetInput(List<Name> names);
```

Comment: What is `List`? It is *not* in the C++03 or C++11 standards....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targeting [c++/cli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI), this code compiles fine (note the enum is now a managed enum, not an unmanaged one like the one you define):

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

public enum class Name
{
    one, two, three,
};

void GetInput(List<Name> names);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should switch to a better, more [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (or C++03) conforming, compiler and/or use `std::list` instead of `List`. The following code

```
 #include <list>
 enum Name {
    one, two, three
 };
 void GetInput(std::list<Name> names);
```

is accepted without warnings with `g++-4.8 -Wall -std=c++11 -c us.cc` on Linux. I am using the just released [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) version. But the same example is also accepted with the older `g++-4.6 -Wall -c us.cc` using some previous C++ standard.

Notice that I am using `std::list` (because `List` is *not* in the C++2011 standard - and also not in previous standards like C++03). Perhaps your compiler might be more happy with `std::list` [instead of `List`] (or maybe `std::vector`, or some other standard C++11 [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)) which is standard?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, both methods of doing this seem to work fine

Comment: `std::list` is not work like `List`, it works like `LinkedList`. `List` is analog of `std::vector`.